# Ideal of the Spinor variety $S^{10}\subset\mathbb{P}^{15}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, projective-geometry, grassmannians, homogeneous-spaces

The ideal of the $10$-dimensional Spinor variety $S^{10}\subset\mathbb{P}^{15}$ is generated by $10$ quadrics.

Does anyone know a reference where these 10 quadratic equations are written down explicitly in the homogeneous coordinates $[x_0:\dots:x_{15}]$ of $\mathbb{P}^{15}$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mukai, [CURVES AND SYMMETRIC SPACES, I](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2375032), (0.1)